# Figure floating takes full page

Tags: subfloats, groupplots

I have about 6 scatter plots which I group together in a single figure by using the subfigure package.
I am using a two-column conference layout. The figure I create is a figure* to extend over both columns.

```
    \begin{figure*}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.90]     
    %content
    \end{tikzpicture}         
    \end{subfigure}      
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.90]     
    %content
    \end{tikzpicture}         
    \end{subfigure}     
     % and so on.... 
    \end{figure*}
```

The plotting itself works, but the figure is always placed on an entirely empty page. I try to set forcefully the "here" flag, but whatever I do the figure is placed on an empty page.
It is not as big as it would  need the whole space, but Latex seems to see things differently here. As is, I exceed a page limit I have.

Does anyone have an idea how I could force Latex into letting text flow around my subfigure-figure-group?

Comment: I bet there just isn't enough space on the page for any text. Nevertheless, the `[h]`ere flag won't work with double-column figures. That stuff is always printed at the top of the page, or on a page of its own.

Comment: whether a double column float is allowed to go onto a text page above two columns of text or if it needs to go on a page of its own depends entirely on the size of the figure (not its content so you could make a test example with just `\begin{figure*}XXX\\[5cm]XXX\end{figure*}`), the size of the page, and the values of the float parameters. Your example doesn't show any of those things, so it is hard to comment. Please fix it so it is a complete document with the float going on to a page on its own, so we can reproduce it here.

Comment: Once again, this looks like a job for \afterpage{\clearpage} from the afterpage package.